# Azure Table Query : System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.'

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I'm occasionally getting following error during my table execute query

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.'

```
private CloudTable table;

    public AzureTableManager(string _CloudTableName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_CloudTableName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Table", "Table Name can't be empty");
        }
        try
        {
            string ConnectionString = PrimariusOMS.Properties.Settings.Default.AzureTableStorage.ToString();
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

            table = tableClient.GetTableReference(_CloudTableName);
            table.CreateIfNotExists();
        }
        catch (StorageException StorageExceptionObj)
        {
            throw StorageExceptionObj;
        }
        catch (Exception ExceptionObj)
        {
            throw ExceptionObj;
        }
    }

    public List<T> RetrieveEntity<T>(string TenantName, string Query = null) where T : TableEntity, new()
    {
TableQuery<T> DataTableQuery = new TableQuery<T>();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Query))
            {
                Query += " and PartitionKey eq '" + TenantName + "'";
            }
            else { Query = "PartitionKey eq '" + TenantName + "'"; }

            DataTableQuery = new TableQuery<T>().Where(Query);
            IEnumerable<T> IDataList = table.ExecuteQuery(DataTableQuery);
            List<T> DataList = new List<T>();
            foreach (var singleData in IDataList)
                DataList.Add(singleData);
            return DataList;
}
```

Error is returned here :

```
IEnumerable<T> IDataList = table.ExecuteQuery(DataTableQuery);
```

This is my sample call:

```
List<AzureTableManager.DTTConfig> dtt = TableManagerObj.RetrieveEntity<AzureTableManager.DTTConfig>(tenantID, "RowKey eq 'Mass WhatIf'");
```

In SQL connections, use to overcome this by USING block or ensuring the reader is closed.
How do I handle it here?

Comment: Can you share the complete code? I have never seen `DataReader` and `Command` with Azure Tables before this question.

Comment: @GauravMantri - added rest of the code. This is actually standard calls from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table. There is no explicit DataReader calls here.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. Can you tell me which line of code throws the error you're getting? Also, please share the code where you're calling `RetrieveEntity`.

Comment: @GauravMantri appended to my question. Please note that call sometimes done every second.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to update your reference to the latest version of `WindowsAzure.Storage`.

In the new version, the `CloudTable` class no longer contains `ExecuteQuery` method. Instead, it has `ExecuteQueryAsync` and `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync` methods.

This code works for me for getting data:

```
public static async Task<List<T>> ExecuteQueryToListAsync<T>(this CloudTable table, TableQuery<T> query) where T : ITableEntity, new()
{
    var result = new List<T>();

    TableContinuationToken token = null;
    do
    {
        TableQuerySegment<T> seg = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, token);
        token = seg.ContinuationToken;
        result.AddRange(seg);
    }
    while (token != null);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm indeed using the latest version - 9.3.3 which exposes both ExecuteQuery and ExecuteQueryAsync. Its somehow working again without any code changes, hence I can't validate your suggestions. Its maybe time to upgrade to https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table